# Forcing the system to allow me to insert any character in the file name

Tags: filenames, special-characters

I had an exam this week, and one of the questions was (with one correct answer):

> The file name can contain the character:
>
> a) `\`
>
> b) `/`
>
> c) `?`
>
> d) `!`

I chose `c) ?` because it looked OK to me. When I came home I tested it on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04) and the file was created successfully. In the ready reckoner the correct answer is marked to be `d) !`.

I knew that the exam was Windows specific, but on the test paper the platform was not specified.

---

It's clear that `\` and `/` characters are not supported in a file name, **BUT** is there any way to force the operating system to allow them?

It would be really cool to proove that even `\` and `/` characters are supported.

Comment: In MS Windows, d) is the correct answer.

Comment: @choroba I know, but on Linux `?` is correct as well. Also, the platform was not specified. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two limiting factors when considering the characters permitted in a file name — restrictions related to the operating system, and restrictions related to the file system. For this question I will assume we are talking about recent versions of Linux and ext4.

Linux only disallows two characters in filenames: `/`, because it is the path separator, and `\0` (ASCII NUL), because it terminates cstrings. In addition to this, the special names `.` and `..` are also reserved by the filesystem for use as navigational hard links.

You can easily demonstrate that the other characters mentioned in your question are allowed:

```
$ touch '\' '?' '!'
$ ls
!  ?  \
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to force the system to accept `/` as well? I know it's a restriction, but maybe there are workarounds...

Comment: @IonicăBizău Almost certainly not through conventional methods. You could try using `debugfs`, but you should expect bad things to happen if you succeed.

Comment: I don't care about bad things, how can I use `debugfs` to create a file named `foo/bar`, for example?

Comment: @IonicăBizău you can also [cheat](http://unicode-table.com/en/). Try copying this into a terminal: `touch 'foo̸̸ bar'`

Comment: @terdon That's a good idea, but not perfect. This is perfect: [`touch 'foo ∕ bar'`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2215/index.htm). So, Chris, you can update your answer and I will mark it! :-)

Comment: @IonicăBizău this is still cheating. Neither character is an actual slash so this is _not_ a way to allow slashes in filenames. It is just a way to make humans think they're allowed. The computer is not fooled.

Comment: @terdon It is, but it's closer to the real slash. :-)